# tomcat classloader priority in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a java application that is deployed on Tomcat 7,

In `/webapps/ws/WEB-INF/lib` I have a JAR which also contains other JARs but I do not want to use them because they are on my `/webapps/ws/WEB-INF/lib` and they have a different version, so I want to add a priority for it to run the JARs that are in the lib

I use Maven to generate the war

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
     <warName>ws</warName>
     <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
  <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
    </manifest>
  </archive>                
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by declaring explicitly your library under dependencices in your pom.

For eg:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Here, tika-core 1.17 dependent on guava 17.0. If you declare guava 23.0 as explicit dependency of your project, it will take precedence over guava 17.0